# jQuery: Live Update Value of Input

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, input

This is what I've started out with and it only changes input#user_name upon running the script. How do I get it to live update the value?

```
var $username = $("input#user_email").val();

$("input#user_name").val($username);
```

Comment: what do you mean "live update the value"?

Comment: btw, I've read that its usually a better idea (for performance) to omit the tag selector when using id's.  So `$("#user_name")` would be preferred.

Comment: @shanabus where did you read that?

Comment: I've seen it in a few places. Here is one that was linked to in another SO post - http://www.componenthouse.com/article-19

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$("input#user_email").keyup(function(){
  $("input#user_name").val($(this).val());
});
```

if what you mean is that when you type on user_email you want that on user_name

Answer (score 4):

```
$(function(){
  $('input#user_email').bind('keyup',function(){
     $("input#user_name").val($(this).val());
  });

});
```